# jQuery: How to select class that includes two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have images, each with two classes. Here is the relevant portion of the HTML.

```
class = "thing other0-a"
class = "thing other1-a"
class = "thing other2-a"
class = "thing other3-a"
class = "thing other0-b"
class = "thing other1-b"
class = "thing other2-b"
```

How can I use jQuery to select classes with "thing" and if it includes "-a"?

I know how to do [class*=-a] but I don't know how to combine selecting for an exact match AND an includes match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of **AND** in jQuery:

```
$("[class*=thing][class*=-a]")
```

The equivalent of **OR** in jQuery:

```
$("[class*=thing],[class*=-a]")
```

The **NOT** function    `:not`

```
$(":not([class*=thing])")  means which doesnt contain "thing"
```

Comment: This is helpful! Is there a "not" as well? Or "not includes"?

Comment: yes see `:not`   https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can declare two attributes with the desired classes in the selector. Like this:

```
div[class*=-a][class*=thing]
```

In this case, the match will be exact.

```js
$('div[class*=-a][class*=thing]').css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "thing other0-a">text</div>
<div class = "thing other1-a">text</div>
<div class = "thing other2-a">text</div>
<div class = "thing other3-a">text</div>
<div class = "thing other0-b">text</div>
<div class = "thing other1-b">text</div>
<div class = "thing other2-b">text</div>
```